# brew install docker-machine-driver-xhive

Tags: linux, homebrew

I am trying to install `docker-machine-driver-xhive`  using `brew`, as part of learning Kubernetes.

I followed the steps specified in following link:

https://www.tecmint.com/linuxbrew-package-manager-for-linux/

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' && sudo yum install curl file git

sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"

echo 'export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin/:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc
echo 'export MANPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"' >>~/.bashrc
echo 'export INFOPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"' >>~/.bashrc
source  ~/.bashrc
```

All these command are executed successfully, without any error.

This is my ~/.bashrc file

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin/:$PATH"
export MANPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin/:$PATH"
export MANPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Now when i try to run `brew` command, i am getting this message.

```
bash: brew: command not found...
```

My OS details are as follows:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
```

The OS is running on Oracle VM Virtual Box.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I‘m afraid you‘re on the wrong OS. The xhyve driver is only for macOS. But for your brew missing problem. Have you tried to ‘locate brew‘?
This might show where the command is located.

Comment: I did ```locate brew```. It generated output. I scanned the entire output but could not find the brew command.

Thanks for pointing out that **xhyve driver is only for macOS**

Comment: Can you follow this? https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/6033